# Is $\{0\}$is borel set in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})?$ yes/no

Tags: measure-theory

Is   $\{0\}$is  borel set in   $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})?$

My attempt : since  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b, \infty )$

so my answer is  **No**

Comment: You should be more explicit in how **No** follows from your attempt. It's easy to see that some sets that belong to the Borel sets if you're given sets that generate it (those sets, at most countable unions of those sets, at most countable intersections of those sets will belong), but I don't think you can determine easily from a collection of generating sets what ***doesn't*** belong. This aspect of your question is more problematic to me than not being able to solve this problem, by the way (i.e. not recognizing an incorrect/incomplete proof is worse than not being able to give a proof).

Comment: Al open sets and all closed sets are Borel sets. It is hard find  a non-Borel set!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro im sorry for that...actually  i was using the definition of Borel set  that  it is  the smallest  $\sigma$ algebra which contain  all of the open set .And here $\{0\}$ is singleton set and singleton set is not open   so  i say **No**

Comment: Regarding the comment by @Kavi Rama Murthy see this [18 January 2007 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/e-Du6qn-oKs/m/OIYIEjZEbpIJ).

Comment: Notice that $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ are Borel sets. Therefore so is the complement of their union, which is...?

Comment: u mean $A=((-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty) )^C= 0$ @Bungo $ \bigcup A = \{0\} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The correct answer is **Yes**.

To see why, remember $\mathcal{B}$ allows *countable* intersections of generating sets. Can you write $\{ 0 \}$ as such a countable  intersection? You might want to consider the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: u mean  $ \cap_{ r\in \mathbb{Q}} (-1/r,1/r)= \{0\}$ ? @HallaSurvivor  can u elaborate more i am not getting

Comment: I would use $r \in \mathbb{N}$ instead. But yes, that's the idea. This is a countable intersection of open sets (and thus is borel), and is also $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: okss thanks u got it @HallaSurvivor